# Getting extra space around my UILabel as it increases in size

Tags: swift, uitableview, uilabel

So, currently, as my label increases in size, the border around the label increases as well. This causes unwarranted layout qualms.

I've been tinkering with the storyboard for hours, but I can't seem to remove that excess border space.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Constraints
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please edit your question to include information about the constraints on your label.

Answer (score 0):

Well usually people would create this in code, I may have a solution that could help you. Since you wanted a storyboard fix, I shall give you that. When you click on your label under attribute inspector, change your label from plain to attributed. Then you will see ... as in more options. Click that and now adjust indentation and add indentation for first line. You could also add indentation for the end. See my picture for example. I did not figure out how to do the top. [image: example]

I would personally suggest you to configure the label in code as it will be easier in the future.

Comment: I tried, but nope. How would you fix it in code, it IS implemented in code as well.